# VPN - Took to long to start application

Tags: eclipse, oracle, tomcat, vpn

I have a java web service application which i run in my local machine using Eclipse and tomcat as my server. Through VPN, i connect to the Oracle database(Because the network for the database that i'll be connecting to is based in another country). But when i run the application in my web browser i takes 10 minutes just to login and go to the main menu screen. What are the possible problems why is it taking so long to load?

I accessed the database in Toad Oracle and tried a query but it only took seconds for the results to show. And thru VPN, i also ping the database and had this results:

```
 Pinging 192.168.1.6 with 32 bytes of data:
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=181ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=174ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=178ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=249ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=166ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=179ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=169ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=657ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=532ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=192ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=205ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=173ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=198ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=181ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=342ms TTL=63
 Request timed out.
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=190ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=182ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=318ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=215ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=182ms TTL=63     
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=478ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=182ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=206ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=209ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=479ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=648ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=1231ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=207ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=226ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=165ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=216ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=290ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=211ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=234ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=360ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=281ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=304ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=327ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=249ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=270ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=199ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=234ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=236ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=195ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=179ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=202ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=168ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=181ms TTL=63
 Reply from 192.168.1.6: bytes=32 time=186ms TTL=63
```

Comment: Does your web application actually connect to the Oracle database for login purposes? If yes, do you have the exact queries that it runs on the Oracle server during the login process? My bet is there is some other process that slows it down and not the connection to the database

Comment: Is your application loading a lot of data at startup/login? Is it retrieving data a row at a time, or with a sensible buffer size (vis `setFetchSize)`)? Still unlikely to take quite that long - maybe check the logs on the client and server for SQL*Net issues or warnings.